# How is simchah (joy/enthusiasm) attained?

Tags: mitzvah, simchah-joy-happiness, emotions, chessed

I want to perform mitzvah's with Simchah. I do what I'm supposed to do out of obligation whether I want to or not but the problem is sometimes I feel tired or I feel lazy (especially when someone needs a favor from me [the mitzvah of chessed]). Or at times I lack motivation.

Therefore,  How can I cultivate the attribute of simchah (joy/enthusiasm) so that I may serve the Lord (through performing mitzvot) with fire (passion!) in my soul?  I want to feel like I won the lottery when doing a mitzvah but sometimes that feeling isn't there. I NEED THAT FIRE! HELP ME PLEASE!

Comment: Dude, if you're a Jew, you've already won the lottery. The relationship you can have with Hashem is the envy of the world. Review Psalm 19 and Psalm 119 and remember the beauty and tremendous value of mitzvot. Honey and gold, man. Get a copy of The Garden of Emunah by Rabbi Arush/Rabbi Lazer Brody and put some emunah in your mitzvot. Then fire up Psalm 100 and serve Hashem with gladness! The notion of having a personal relationship with Hashem is a Jewish idea. Take it back! And take 15 minutes for hitbodedut in your native tongue. Make Hashem a proud Father!

Comment: I'm just trying to establish a holy relationship with the creator to the best of my abilities as a humble gentile.

Comment: If you're a Gentile, you don't have the mitzvah of chesed. Gentiles can voluntarily take on some of the mitzvot of the Jews, but since we are not obligated, the benefits to us are not the same. We have a different relationship with the Creator. If you want the joy of the mitzvot, you need to become a Jew. Otherwise, learn about the path of the Righteous Gentile as a Noahide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some that translate [the pasuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.100.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "עִבְדוּ אֶת־יְהֹוָה בְּשִׂמְחָה" not as "serve Hashem with joy", but "if you serve Hashem, you will be b'simcha"

The truth behind this is profound: it is not possible to attain happiness through self-service. In fact, when we are concerned about our own needs, we are definitionally not happy, but rather we are anxious, stressed and depressed. After many years of taking this approach, and filling in the void of happiness with yeitzer haras like food and cheap thrills, we eventually start to question what is the point.

Why were we created? So that we should be given needs and problems to worry about? We meant to spend our whole life pursuing our needs, under huge effort for little reward? The younger people realise that this isn't the way, the better.

Happiness comes when we realise that we didn't create ourselves, or our needs. Someone else created us, and He asks us to do something *for Him*. What a relief! Now we know our purpose, which is the first pre-requisite to finding happiness! Secondly, we have won the lottery! We have an opportunity to serve Hashem! Whatever He needs, we will do, and that's where we will find true, lasting *simcha*.

Hopefully we can learn this before we discover it through life experience, such as having a spouse and children to serve. Many people discover the joy of service at that point in their lives, and often it is quite too late - a lot of damage done. *Hatzlacha*!

---

All of this is based on Rabbi Manis Friedman's lectures on this huge topic, so [here is a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiJ2-AAp8-s&list=PL1R4vEmVBZSy-HdLNscieecKluKUiy4Dy) if you'd like to hear more. The sources are mainly chassidus, as he is a Chabad chassid.